# Is there a way to parse html tags with Python?

Tags: python, html-parsing

I need to parse several HTML tags.

Example:
I need to turn:

```
<div class="title">
     <h1> Hello World </h1>
</div>
```

into

```
['<div class="title">', '<h1> Hello World </h1>', '</div>']
```

Comment: You could do this example with [`ElementTree.iterparse`](https://docs.python.org/3/library/xml.etree.elementtree.html#xml.etree.ElementTree.iterparse) but its for well-formatted XML, not messy HTML. There is also lxml's iterwalk [here](https://lxml.de/parsing.html#iterparse-and-iterwalk) - in this case use lxml's html parser to build the doc and then iterwalk to get start and end tags.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can use a recursive generator function with `BeautifulSoup`:

```
import bs4
from bs4 import BeautifulSoup as soup
s = """
<div class="title">
   <h1> Hello World </h1>
</div>
"""
def get_tags(d):
   ats = " ".join(a+"="+f'"{(b if not isinstance(b, list) else " ".join(b))}"' for a, b in d.attrs.items())
   h = f'<{d.name} {ats}>' if ats else f'<{d.name}>'
   if (k:=[i for i in d.contents if isinstance(i, bs4.element.Tag)]):
      yield h
      yield from [j for l in k for j in get_tags(l)]
      yield f'</{d.name}>'
   else:
      yield f'{h}{d.text}</{d.name}>'

print(list(get_tags(soup(s, 'html.parser').contents[1])))
```

Output:

```
['<div class="title">', '<h1> Hello World </h1>', '</div>']
```

Comment: @MyDisplay Glad to help!

Answer (score 0):

you can use split by ('><')

and add again "><" to the strings from list

Comment: This parses individual tags, I need to parse the tag with the nested content. My output was `['<', '<div class="title"> ', '<h1> Hello World ', '</h1> ', '</div>']`, however, I need `['<div class="title">', '<h1> Hello World </h1>', '</div>']`.

Comment: Please provide additional details in your answer. As it's currently written, it's hard to understand your solution.